# MySQL 8 Community Replication: Achieving Data Synchronization Between Nodes

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I've set up a MySQL 8 replication scenario with Node 1 and Node 2 in a Master-Master configuration using binlog positions. In the event of Node 1 being down, Node 2 functions correctly due to the Master-Master setup. However, if Node 2 is down while Node 1 is up, Node 1 does not receive updated data because automatic replication from Node 2 to Node 1 isn't occurring.

My approach involved traditional Master-Master replication using binlog positions.

I'm seeking guidance or suggestions on how to ensure data synchronization between Node 1 and Node 2 consistently, even when one of the nodes experiences downtime. Is there a solution or method to facilitate automatic replication from Node 2 to Node 1 when Node 2 is restored after downtime?

Any assistance or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wanting to use MySQL replication in the first place? (Master-Master replication is never as simple as it sounds). Is your objective high-availability, or to scale-out performance, or geographic distribution for performance? Or something else?